# UIAlertView showing several times

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I've got a simple `UIAlertView` showing when user runs the app. It has this structure:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome!", "")
                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"This is a welcome message.", "")                             
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

The question is, How can I customize it to show every 5 runs for example?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: `every 5 runs` - do you mean every 5 times app start execution?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer about "every 5 runs"

Comment: Yeah, every 5 times app start execution ;) It's on the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store app executions count for key `AppRunCount` (you can introduce your own key name):

```
int runCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AppRunCount"] + 1

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:runCount forKey:@"AppRunCount"];

if (runCount <= 5) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome!", "")
                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"This is a welcome message.", "")                             
                                           delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

You can just add code above to `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Ok works perfect. Now, what if I want the alert to show on the first, the 6th, the 11th,... every 5 times the app starts?

Comment: just change condition in `if`-statement from `runCount <= 5` to `runCount % 5 == 1`

Answer (score 1):

There will be a method in AppDelegate class like

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Now create one NSUSerdefaults in this method and make one integer  and increment that integer and save it in NSUserdefaults

Now every time application starts that method will be called and integer will incremented

Now make if condition in that method like below

```
if(your integer which has nsuserdefaults >=5)
{
   your alertview
    again here make your nsinteger  to Zero which is stored in nsuserdefaults 
     your integer which has nsuserdefaults =0
}
```

This is the answer of your second question,Every after 5 times app run. alert will be pop up
Let me know it is working or not..!!!!
Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: This works too, and the first one changing the code to runCount % 5 == 1  works also. Thanks NiravPatel